# Hash password in sendResetPwd

Tags: hash, reset-password, feathers-authentication

When trying to reset password with feathers.js, vue and feathers-authentication-management appears that tokens and passwords are not hashed the same. I am looking for an recent application that does all the things that feathers authentication management says it does. So far all examples have fallen short.

Comment: Also using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that the examples have fallen short. But me. There is assumption knowledge needed to complete the examples.